# Hide user fields based off capability

Tags: user-roles, user-meta, capabilities, profiles

I'm struggling with this one. I am trying to hide 2 user profile fields for the current user. Only the admin or user with "edit_users" capability should be able to view/edit these fields.

Code:

```
function modify_contact_methods($profile_fields) {

    // Field addition and removal will be done here
    // Add new fields
    $profile_fields['company_name'] = 'Company Name';
    $profile_fields['company_id'] = 'Company ID';

    if(current_user_can('edit_users')) {
        return $profile_fields;
    }
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'modify_contact_methods');
```

Now it displays fine when the user is an admin, but if the user doesn't have the 'edit_users' capability, this error shows on the page between the other contact fields:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/wp-admin/user-edit.php on line 421

How can I correctly code it so it doesn't come up with this error? Any ideas?
Any suggestion/code example is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This filter needs to return something. Try this

```
function modify_contact_methods($profile_fields) {
    if(current_user_can('edit_users')) {
        // Field addition and removal will be done here
        // Add new fields
        $profile_fields['company_name'] = 'Company Name';
        $profile_fields['company_id'] = 'Company ID';
    }

    return $profile_fields;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'modify_contact_methods');
```